# How to remove an item from list of maps based on specific key?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following list

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filterItems = [
     {"category":1},
     {"option_val":1},
      
 ]
```

I also have the following map

```
 Map<String, dynamic> singleItem = {"category":6}
```

I would like to remove any item from the list above (filterItems) which has an object with key similar to singleItem map. So in my case i would like to remove the `{"category":1}` from the list since it has a key category similar to the map.

So i have tried the following

```
filterItems.remove(singleItem);
print(filterItems)
```

But the above doesnt work since the value of key is different so i tried the following where am now stuck on how to proceed

```
singleItem.map((key,value){
    filterItems.removeWhere((element) => element.containsKey(key))
})
```

But the above throws an error that the body of `singleItem.map` is returning null. How can I proceed to remove an item from the list when a key matches even though the value is different?

Comment: `filterItems.removeWhere((item) => item.keys.first == singleItem.keys.first);` or even: `filterItems.removeWhere((item) => item.keys.single == singleItem.keys.single);`

Answer (score 5):

you can use `.removeWhere` as follow:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filterItems = [
     {"category":1},
     {"option_val":1},
      
 ];
  Map<String, dynamic> singleItem = {"category":6};
  
  filterItems.removeWhere((element) => element.keys.first == singleItem.keys.first);
  print(filterItems);
```

and the result would be:

```
[{option_val: 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove when a list has the same key

```
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> filterItems = [
      {"category": 1},
      {"option_val": 1},
    ];

    Map<String, dynamic> singleItem = {"category": 6};

    filterItems = filterItems.where((e) {
      return e.keys.toString() != singleItem.keys.toString();
    }).toList();
```